# Find date of each week in from week in Spark Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I want to add a column with date of each corresponding week in Dataframe (appending friday in each date)
My Dataframe looks like this

```
+----+------+---------+

|Week| City|sum(Sale)|
+----+------+---------+
| 29|City 2| 72|
| 28|City 3| 48|
| 28|City 2| 19|
| 27|City 2| 16|
| 28|City 1| 84|
| 28|City 4| 72|
| 29|City 4| 39|
| 27|City 3| 42|
| 26|City 3| 68|
| 27|City 1| 89|
| 27|City 4| 104|
| 26|City 2| 19|
| 29|City 3| 27|
+----+------+---------+
```

I need to convert it as below dataframe

```
----+------+---------+---------------  |
|Week| City|sum(Sale)|perticular day(dd/mm/yyyy)  |
+----+------+---------+---------------|
| 29|City 2| 72|Friday(07/21/2017)|
| 28|City 3| 48|Friday(07/14/2017)|
| 28|City 2| 19|Friday(07/14/2017)|
| 27|City 2| 16|Friday(07/07/2017)|
| 28|City 1| 84|Friday(07/14/2017)|
| 28|City 4| 72|Friday(07/14/2017)|
| 29|City 4| 39|Friday(07/21/2017)|
| 27|City 3| 42|Friday(07/07/2017)|
| 26|City 3| 68|Friday(06/30/2017)|
| 27|City 1| 89|Friday(07/07/2017)|
| 27|City 4| 104|Friday(07/07/2017)|
| 26|City 2| 19|Friday(06/30/2017)|
| 29|City 3| 27|Friday(07/21/2017)|
+----+------+---------+
```

please help me

Comment: what is the value for week 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a simple UDF and get the date from adding week in it.

Here is the simple example

```
import spark.implicits._
val data = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
  (29,"City 2", 72),
  (28,"City 3", 48),
  (28,"City 2", 19),
  (27,"City 2", 16),
  (28,"City 1", 84),
  (28,"City 4", 72),
  (29,"City 4", 39),
  (27,"City 3", 42),
  (26,"City 3", 68),
  (27,"City 1", 89),
  (27,"City 4", 104),
  (26,"City 2", 19),
  (29,"City 3", 27)
)).toDF("week", "city", "sale")


val getDateFromWeek = udf((week : Int) => {
  //create a default date for week 1
  val week1 = LocalDate.of(2016, 12, 30)
  val day = "Friday"
  //add week from the week column 
  val result = week1.plusWeeks(week).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy"))
  //return result as Friday (date)
  s"${day} (${result})"
})

//use the udf and create a new column named day
data.withColumn("day", getDateFromWeek($"week")).show
```

can anyone convert this to Pyspark?

Comment: City|Month|Sale
c1|1|49
c1|2|46
c1|4|83
c2|1|59
c2|5|60
c2|6|49
c2|7|73

Comment: City|Month|Sale
c1|1|49
c1|2|46
c1|4|83
c2|1|59
c2|5|60
c2|6|49
c2|7|73

Create a data frame,

1)  Compute previous month sale (previous_month _sale)
2)  Compute percentage change in sale (pct_change)
3)  Compute current month sales as percentage of max sale in any month (pct_of_max_sale)

Comment: do you want me to do that for you ??